# Unable to transfer adjacency list data and convert it into a adjacency matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, list, matrix

My code first takes in user input where:

- `n` = the number of vertices in a graph
- `file` = the file to compute

In this case, my file is a .txt file containing:

```
0 1  
2 1  
0 2  
1 3
```

My code successfully converts this into an adjacency list with the output `[[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0], [1]]`. The problem however, is to convert it into a adjacency matrix. I am aware that the main problem with my code is at this line:

```
for x in range(len(vertices)):
    matrix[z-1][vertices[x]] = 1
```

Here is my full code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of vertices: ")) ## E.g. 4
file = input("Enter the filename: ") ## E.g. graph.txt

vertices = []
matrix = [] ## define list

for x in range(n):
    matrix.append([0]*n]) ## append a list for n, e.g. if n = 4 then [[][][][]]
    vertices.append([])

f =open(file)

z = 0
for line in f: ##loop statement until no more line in file
    line = line.split() ## turn every line into a list
    z+=1



    for y in range(len(line)):
        line[y] = line[y].strip() ## remove spaces
        line[y] = int(line[y]) ## converts line list into integer
           ## add  value of line into main list

    vertices[line[0]].append(line[1])
    vertices[line[1]].append(line[0])



for z in range(len(matrix)):

    for x in range(len(vertices)):
        matrix[z-1][vertices[x]] = 1



print(vertices)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Why are you using `z-1`?  `z`'s initial in that loop is 0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `z-1` as an index which could be -1, so that should just be `z`.

Secondly, you're accessing `vertices[x]` in the inner loop as if it has a node number, but it is a nested list. Instead, you need `vertices[z][x]`. For performance it is in principle better to create a name for `vertices[z]`:

```
for z in range(len(matrix)):
    neighbors = vertices[z]
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        matrix[z][neighbors[x]] = 1
```

Or:

```
for z, neighbors in enumerate(vertices):
    for x in neighbors:
        matrix[z][x] = 1
```